# AWS: How to secure VPC admin to a single IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I have created a VPC with the bare minimum of information: the VPC name, CIDR block, and default tenancy type.  I then created a policy to administer the VPC and added it to a newly created user.  My plan was to then log in as that user and complete the VPC setup, including subnets, EC2 instances, RDS, routing, etc.

The problem is that when I log in the user has no authority at all.  They are not authorised for any EC2 or VPC services.  I can not even see the VPC that I have created.  Presumably there is something wrong with my policy.  Here it is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:999999999999:vpc/vpc-99999999"
        }
    ]
}
```

(Obviously that's not the real account number or VPC ID.)

Do I just need an additional permission to the IAM service?  If so, what is it?  Or is it more complex than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what permissions you exactly wish to provide. However, the following will give you a large amount of access, localized to the specific VPC you wish to administer.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:vpc/vpc-1a2b3c4d"
                }
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

(Update region, account, and vpc id in the above)